# Sorting temperatures in a array list using insertion sort algorithm in java

Tags: java, printing, comparable, insertion-sort

I am working on a program that will take a list of temperatures(double) and days(string) and implement the list using an array of objects.  Then I need to sort the objects using an insertion sort algorithm.  The output of the program should be the original order and the sorter output.  However I am a little confused on how I can go about sorting the temperatures.  I implemented the Comparable interface and wrote the insertion sort.  I just have to have the original arraylist to print out and the sorted arraylist to print out. I wrote a toString method to print out the original and it compiles but does not print. here is my code:

```
 import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class DailyTemperature implements Comparable<DailyTemperature>
{
     //variables
    private Double temperature;
    private String day;

    //getTemp & setTemp methods
    public double getTemp()
    {
      return temperature;
    }

    public void setTemp(double newTemp)
    {
      temperature = newTemp;
    }

    //getDay & setTEmp methods
    public String getDay()
    {
      return day;
    }

    public void setDay(String newDay)
    {
      day = newDay;
    }


    public DailyTemperature(String day, double temperature) 
    {
      this.day = day;
      this.temperature = temperature;
    }

    public int compareTo(DailyTemperature other) 
    {
        if (temperature < other.temperature) return -1;
        if (temperature == other.temperature) return 0;
        return 1;
    }

    public String toString() 
    {
        return("Day of Week" + this.getDay() +
        "Temperature" + this.getTemp());
    }


}





import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DailyTemperatureList 
{
    public static void main (String [] args) 
    {

    ArrayList<DailyTemperature> dailytemps = new ArrayList<DailyTemperature>();

    dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Mon", 87.1));
    dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Tue", 88.3));
    dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Wed", 81.2));
    dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Thu", 84.0));
    dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Fri", 76.3));
   }

   public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
   void insertionSort(ArrayList<DailyTemperature> dailytemps)
   {
       DailyTemperature temp = null;
       int position = 0;

       //loop from 2nd element on
       for (int i = 1; i < dailytemps.size(); i++)
       {
           temp = dailytemps.get(i);
           position = i;

           while ( 0 < position && temp.compareTo(dailytemps.get(position - 1 )) < 0)
           {
               dailytemps.set(position, dailytemps.get(position - 1));
               position--;
           }
            dailytemps.set(position,temp);
        }
        System.out.println( dailytemps.toString() );
    }




}
```

Comment: Are you sorting by day or by value?

Comment: @JasperHolton by the value

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the method `public int compareTo(DailyTemperature)` that is required for the Comparable interface

```
public class DailyTemperature implements Comparable<DailyTemperature>{

   //...

   public int compareTo(DailyTemperature other){

      //your code goes here if "this"< than other, return a negative int
      //if this > other return positive int
      //if they are equal in the eyes of sort, then return 0

   }
```

}

EDIT:  your sort would use the comparables like this

```
 DailyTemperature a = ...
 DailyTemperature b = ...

 if(a.compareTo(b) < 0){
     // a < b
 }else{
     // a >=b

 }
```

Comment: Can i use an insertion sort with Comparable? Or does comparable pretty much replace the sort algorithm?

Comment: Comparable can be used to answer "given 2 temperatures, which is less than the other?".  You can use this in any sort algorithm you write to determine the "where to swap" part.

Comment: where would i use the comparable in the insertion sort? I am confused on how I can use the comparable in the insertion sort.

Comment: are a and b equal to the temperatures? and im not sure how to move the temperatures into the correct order.  Our professor never taught us insertion sort so i'm really confused :/

Answer (score 0):

@dkatzel is spot on. I would only add that you can take some more advantage of the facilities provided by Java out of the box by making your `compareTo` implementation tighter:

Here is the same class edited for brevity:

```
public class DailyTemperature implements Comparable<DailyTemperature>
{
     //variables
    private Double temperature;

    public int compareTo(DailyTemperature other) {
        return temperature.compareTo(other.temperature);
    }

}
```

If you store temperature internally as a `Double` and take advantage of autoboxing (which lets you go from `double` <-> `Double` seamlessly...ish), you can then take advantage of the fact `Double` implements `Comparable` and delegate the `compareTo` implementation in your custom class to `Double`'s.

Then you do your insertion sort exactly as @dkatzel said, with the `temperature.compareTo` calls replacing the usual primitive comparisons.

Coincidentally, we just finished a [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pq0ArQhhWzU) on comparisons in Java. Have a look if you want some more explanation on how they work.

Hope that helps.

Comment: What do a and b equal in dkatzel's insertion sort algorithm? Do i have to make them equal to a different temperature?